# Cannot click a button using Python Selenium on a certain website

Tags: python, html, selenium, iframe

I have been trying to click a button on a website to close a pop-up(specifically Google Vignette). I will say I am a beginner.
If you want to see the html, please follow the steps.

This is the website : https://www.finscreener.org/earnings/earnings-reported?o=1001&pg=1

But you will have to click the **"last button"** at the bottom index, since Google Vignette only pops up when you try to get out of the current website.

If you want to inspect it, then maximize the window, right click somewhere outside of the pop-up. If not, the pop up will disappear and you cannot inspect.

Anyways, when the Google ad appears I want to dismiss it.
I tried the code below to change the iframe to the advertisement,

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ad_iframe')))
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//iframe[@name='ad_iframe']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

But the code cannot locate the iframe and gives me a TimeoutException for the WebDriverWait line.

I have tried the following, but the code absolutely refuses to locate the advertisement iframe.

1. Change to implicit timing
2. try XPath and name

- there is a link of a picture of the iframe html at the bottom
  After locating the iframe I have the following click command - which i cannot carry out right now.

```
close_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]").click()
```

How can i locate the iframe and switch to it?

Comment: Can you clarify more which button will trigger an ad?

Comment: At the bottom of the table, you see the page numbers? 1/2/3/4 next> LAST . Click on LAST and it will trigger.

Comment: I tried. Nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an `iframe` inside another one. You will have to switch two frames to reach the close button.

**Solution 1: Close the ad**

```
with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    # Wait until the frame appears and switch to it
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'aswift_5')))
    driver.switch_to.frame('ad_iframe')
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'dismiss-button').click()
```

You also must include the following imports:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

**Solution 2: Refresh the page**

In you case this might be an easier solution, by refreshing the page it will also "dismiss" the popover.

```
driver.refresh()
```

Comment: @InkyuKim glad to hear and welcome to SO. If this resolved your question, please don't forget to mark the answer as the accepted one. (check mark)